# What is relation between AuthenticationScheme and IIdentity.AuthenticationType

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-authentication

How are they connected? I can use `HttpContext.SignInAsync`, and then `HttpContext.User` is set to provided identity, however I have one identity and multiple authentication ways - what if user login as Customer and then moves to AdminPanel?